# Default Values and Metadata SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, default-value, enterprise-keywords

I'm attempting to set default values on Folder of a Document Library. This used to work well, but now, they are only getting set on Drag n Drop. Not when the user chooses to create a new Document (Word, PP, Excel) from the Drop down menu

As you can see below, the Presentation.pptx was created by clicking the 'New' drop down menu. The DragnDrop.pdf was dragged from File Explorer. Why does the pdf get tagged with a Default value and not the pptx? Is this a bug or expected functionality?

[image]

Comment: And you sure that both files are the same content type?

Comment: There are no content types on this library